# Validate the user's permission in the

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In my system we need to control user's permission by button.
We created a standard function to enable or disable the buttons according the user profile.
But the user can enable the button that was disable through browser DevTolls (F12).

In addition to disabling, I also define ".off('click')" to the button.

What's the best way to confirm if the user really can execute operation?

Comment: Server-side is the way to go.

Comment: Never trust the user. Everything must be validated on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is MVC in the back-end, use C#(Razor) to check for the Condition from the model and display the button instead of using front end java-script to display.

eg:

```
@if(Customer.IsLoggedIn)
{
<input type="button" value="Whatever">
}
```

now, this button would now appear in the browser only if the condition is right.
so, no possibility of manipulation.

Hope this helps... Thank you.